# How to fix 'preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 1828' error in laravel 'url' validation?

Tags: php, laravel, php-7.3

when i use 'url' validation in laravel request then give me error.

> preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 1828

```
$this->validate($request, [
   'posting_article_url' => 'nullable|url',
]);
```

it is occurred in php 7.3. in php 7.2 it is working fine.

when i replace 'url' validation with 'regex:pattern' validation then working fine.

```
$this->validate($request, [
   'posting_article_url' => 'nullable|regex:/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/',
]);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you put here some line of code? 
At least the preg_match(...) line and the used values.

Comment: As I've said: it will help the line with preg_match() and the values used, especially the 1st parameter $pattern.

Comment: The complete error message should be something like:
preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 1828 FILE.php on line NNN
On line NNN you should find the preg_match() call.
Put here the respective line, and print the values passed to preg_match().

Comment: sorry but it is a php 7.3 issue.

Comment: Probable you are hit by this change 7.3 vs. 7.2 :
https://hackernoon.com/deprecations-and-changes-for-php-7-3-avoid-errors-7a5c4dbeaa8b , check "PCRE to PCRE2 migration" , and few lines below you you will find an example which works no more in 7.3 . Because of that is important to know the vallues passed to preg_match() . But if you don't provide the exact line of code and the values passed it will be hard to guess what is the reason.

Comment: @miken32 I don't see a poorly placed hyphen on this one.  I can't replicate.  Do you see something that I don't?

Comment: @mickmackusa I’m assuming it’s inside the Laravel code somewhere. Probably the actual answer on this one is to upgrade Laravel.

Comment: I chose "cannot replicate" instead of dupe hammering this one (I hammered all of your others) -- but my vote was the 5th, so same effect.